# Android MediaPlayer plays two times when i open from another class

Tags: java, android

i would like to make a mediaplayer in android and have an error.
I have two activitys (FileBrowser and MainActivity(with Player)).
When i click on a listitem in my filebrowser i'll send the filepath
to my MainActivity.class.

```
private OnItemClickListener musicgridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                            long id) {
        System.gc();
        music_column_index = musiccursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(Audio.Media.DATA);
        musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
        Uri path = Uri.parse(filename);
        Player.initMusicPlayer(path);
        finish();
    }
};
```

I recieved the path in my "initMusicPlayer" method in my MainActivity.class

```
public void initMusicPlayer(Uri filename){
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    playFile(filename);
}
```

The "playFile" method:

```
    public void playFile(Uri filename){
    Log.i("Filename: ", filename.toString());
    stopPlaying();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,filename);
    player.start();
}
```

The "stopPlaying" method:

```
    private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player != null){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}
```

When i now call the "initMusicPlayer" with a new path the player starts the new file but the old doesn't stop.

Thank for help.

Comment: what happens if you call stopPlaying() method prior to calling playFile()?

Comment: Same error.. the player starts twice and more.

Comment: how are you passing the url to mainactivity ? and have you checked if the following loop is still alive                                                                               if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }                                                                                                          after calling  player.stop(); ?